# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch in Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im trying to submit a form to a spring controller and getting the below exception

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [openmrs] in context with path [/openmrs-standalone] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ForcePasswordChangeFilter.doFilter(ForcePasswordChangeFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilterChain.doFilter(ModuleFilterChain.java:72)
    at org.openmrs.module.owa.filter.OwaFilter.doFilter(OwaFilter.java:57)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilterChain.doFilter(ModuleFilterChain.java:70)
    at org.openmrs.module.web.filter.ModuleFilter.doFilter(ModuleFilter.java:54)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openmrs.web.filter.OpenmrsFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenmrsFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.openmrs.web.filter.StartupFilter.doFilter(StartupFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and my controller looks like this

```
@Controller
public class RunReportFormController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/module/reporting/run/runReport.form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected String initializeForm(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
        // Some logic
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/module/reporting/run/runReport.form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute Object commandObject, BindException errors) throws Exception {
        // some logic
    }
```

Can someone help me understanding what have i done wrong here ? Thanks

Comment: Why it is type Object, protected Object initializeForm

Comment: @Sambit Its just returning some custom object called CommandObject written in the application

Comment: I guess, that may be the problem.

Comment: @Sambit what should be return there ? also this happens when submitting the form not when loading the form

Comment: Do not use Object, use specific object like your CommandObject type.

Comment: @Sambit Sorry im not returning the object there. Im just returning a String. I have changed the return type to String still having the same issue

Comment: Also check what you are getting from ModelMap model.

Answer (score 3):

Managed to fix it after changing the post method signature from BindException to  BindingResult

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/module/reporting/run/runReport.form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected String onSubmit(@ModelAttribute Object commandObject, BindingResult errors) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Spent almost 6 hours to resolve this issue. Above resolution helped. Thank you!